# Redux Toolkit addListener typescript error in component (createListenerMiddleware)

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, redux-toolkit

I am following the [Redux Toolkit's documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#adding-listeners-inside-components) to add a listener in my component as such:

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

...
const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(() => {
    return dispatch(
      addAppListener({
        matcher: isAnyOf(
          updateResponse,
          ...
        ),
        effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
           ...
        }
      })
    )
  }, [])
```

I've also typed the app listener like it recommends in the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#typescript-usage). Here is how I did it for reference:

```js
import { addListener, createListenerMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { TypedAddListener, TypedStartListening } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { AppDispatch, RootState } from './store'

export const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()

export type AppStartListening = TypedStartListening<RootState, AppDispatch>

export const startAppListening =
  listenerMiddleware.startListening as AppStartListening

export const addAppListener = addListener as TypedAddListener<
  RootState,
  AppDispatch
>
```

However, my `useEffect` return in my component is getting the following error:

```
Argument of type '() => { payload: ListenerEntry<EmptyObject & { user: WritableDraft<UserState>; authentication: AuthenticationState; }, ((action: Action<...>) => UnsubscribeListener) & ... 1 more ... & Dispatch<...>>; type: "listenerMiddleware/add"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type '{ payload: ListenerEntry<EmptyObject & { user: WritableDraft<UserState>; authentication: AuthenticationState; }, ((action: Action<...>) => UnsubscribeListener) & ... 1 more ... & Dispatch<...>>; type: "listenerMiddleware/add"; }' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Can you double check the code in your post matches what is producing the error for you locally? The error you posted, to me, reads that you are directly passing `dispatch(addAppListener(....))` as the `useEffect` callback instead of a function that calls `dispatch` as you've posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't using a correctly typed version of `useDispatch` in that component.  It's still just using the basic Redux built-in `Dispatch` type, which doesn't know that you've got the listener middleware set up.

You need to follow our directions for setting up a pre-typed version of `useDispatch` based on your store's configuration, and use that pre-typed hook in this component:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-typed-hooks